# Error when install a gem mysql12 to ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rubygems

i have tried to install mysql12 for ruby, but whenever I execute the command

```
gem install mysql12
```

i will give an error

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mysql12' (>= 0) in any repository

please help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 2):

Please run command in your terminal to avoid 'Building native extensions' exception such as "Le Quang Hoan" get:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then install mysql2 gem not mysql12

```
gem install mysql2
```

Comment: You are assuming the user has Linux with `apt-get`. This is not a safe assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You've mispelled it.  It is `mysql2`, not `mysql12`.